# Is it possible for a generic method to call a method from the type you pass into it

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, undefined

I have a certain method that needs to be used in many classes. This method is meant to create a new List of objects of the given object type. This method would need to call another method from each class (different implementations of the same kind of method).

Rather than copy/paste the method into every class and change the object type every time, I wanted to create a generic class with a generic method that would call the necessary method from each class. Is this possible?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Conversion<E> {
    public static <E> List<E> toList(String str) {
        //The string needs to be split because it contains
        //the information to create multiple objects
        String[] listArray = str.split(".");
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (String s : listArray) {
            //E.fromString() creates an object of the type E
            //It is a static method
            list.add(E.fromString(s));
        }
    return list;
    }
}
```

When I try this, `Eclipse` gives me an error, saying that `fromString(String)` is undefined for the type `E`. Is what I want even possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204121/discussion-on-question-by-orion-is-it-possible-for-a-generic-method-to-call-a-me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest modification is to use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).
Define an interface such as

```
interface Parser<T> {
    T fromString(String s);
}
```

and change the signature to

```
public static <E> List<E> toList(String str, Parser<E> parser) {
```

Then use `parser.fromString(s)`, not `E.fromString`

Sample usage

```
interface User {}

class UserParser implements Parser<User> {
    @Override
    public User fromString(String s) {
        return new User() {};
    }
}



toList("a.b.c", new UserParser());
```

---

**Hypothetical:**

If there was some language feature to make a static method part of an interface's contract, maybe you could get away with something like this

```
interface Parsable<T> {
    static T fromString(String s); // will not compile
}

public static <E extends Parseable<E>> List<E> toList(String str)
```

But that won't ever happen in Java. Wouldn't be surprised if there's another strongly typed language that does allow it, though.

Seems to be some [hot discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600) on whether it should be included into TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I was thinking as well after this brief "discussion" in the comments.

Comment: Regarding your hypothetical, this is for a school project, so I can't exactly switch languages, but it's interesting to note the hypothetical alternative.

Comment: @Orion Oh, I wasn't saying you should switch language. I was just trying to underline the fact that what you're asking for isn't conceptually "wrong" necessarily (see the TypeScript discussion), its just not something that's possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a interface which does conversation from String to type E and pass the object type in your method. like below:

```
public static <E> List<E> toList(String str, YourType<E> yourObject) {
    //The string needs to be split because it contains
    //the information to create multiple objects
    String[] listArray = str.split(".");
    List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
    for (String s : listArray) {
        //E.fromString() creates an object of the type E
        //It is a static method
        list.add(yourObject.fromString(s));
    }
return list;
}
}

interface YourType<E>{
     E fromString(String s);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have `yourObject` and in fact OP's objective is to create `yourObject` using the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

can be done this way but this is very **unsafe**

```
public static class Conversion {
        public static <E> List<E> toList(String str, Class<E> clazz)
                throws Exception {
            //The string needs to be split because it contains
            //the information to create multiple objects
            String[] listArray = str.split("\\.");
            List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
            Method fromStringMethod = clazz.getMethod("fromString", String.class);
            for (String s : listArray) {
                //E.fromString() creates an object of the type E
                //It is a static method
                Object object = fromStringMethod.invoke(null, s);
                list.add((E) object);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }


    public static class FromString {
        private String field;

        public FromString() {
        }
        public FromString(String st) {
            this.field = st;
        }
        static public FromString fromString(String st) {
            return new FromString(st);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FromString{" +
                    "field=" + field +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Conversion.toList("one.two.three", FromString.class));
    }
```

Output:

```
[FromString{field=one}, FromString{field=two}, FromString{field=three}]
```

Comment: Unsafe in what way?

Comment: type checking way

Comment: @Orion To clarify what Nonika said, this approach is unsafe in at least two ways: **(1)** There's no guarantee the `#fromString(String)` method is present in the class, which means `getMethod` can throw a `NoSuchMethodException`; **(2)** The return type of `Method#invoke` is `Object` which you then have to cast to `E` but there's no guarantee that the returned object is of type `E`.

Comment: @Nonika Since the `fromString` method is supposed to be static, you should be using `fromStringMethod.invoke(null, s)`. The first argument of `invoke` is `null` when invoking static methods.